# How to get length of array inside of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Try to get length of array inside an object

[image]

image above is return of **Res**

I want to check if every tenor length is equal or more than zero.

But, I stuck in how to call itemCounter"i" when loop it

```
var tenorCount = Object.keys(res).length;
var flagTenor = false;
try{
    
    for(var i=1;i<tenorCount;i++){ 
        
            if (res.itemCounter_+i.tenor.length < 1){ //Stuck in here
                flagTenor = true;
            }
        
    }
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

How to call itemCounter"i" correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using template literals and computed property names

`` if (res[`itemCounter_${i+1}`].tenor.length < 1) ``

Example

```js
const res = {
  itemCounter_1: {
    tenor: ["one"]
  },
  itemCounter_2: {
    tenor: []
  },
}
var tenorCount = Object.keys(res).length;
var flagTenor = false;
try {

  for (var i = 0; i < tenorCount; i++) {

    if (res[`itemCounter_${i+1}`].tenor.length < 1) {
      flagTenor = true;
    }

  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(flagTenor);
```